# How to regex-replace a string in C++ using a function invoked each match to get the replacement

Tags: javascript, c++, regex, string, replace

How do I write, in modern C++, something similar to this Javascript code:

```
// Example Code From: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace
function replacer(match, p1, p2, p3, offset, string) {
  // p1 is nondigits, p2 digits, and p3 non-alphanumerics
  return [p1, p2, p3].join(' - ');
}
var newString = 'abc12345#$*%'.replace(/([^\d]*)(\d*)([^\w]*)/, replacer);
console.log(newString);  // Prints 'abc - 12345 - #$*%'
```

Comment: Reviewed, more focused, question posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60686287/how-to-replace-parts-of-string-using-a-callback-function-called-each-regex-match). This original question was closed by moderator. Nothing to do here anymore.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include<regex>
#include<string>
#include<iostream>

std::string foo(std::string s)
{
    static const std::regex r {R"~~(^([^\d]*)(\d*)([^\w]*)$)~~"};
    return std::regex_replace(s, r, "$1 - $2 - $3");
}

int main()
{
    std::string s = "abc12345#$*%";
    std::cout << foo(s);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following regex to split the string at the desired locations, between consecutive characters:

```
(?<=[a-z])(?=[0-9#$*%])|(?<=[0-9])(?=[a-z#$*%])|(?<=[#$*%])(?=[a-z0-9])
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/QwDyxW/3/)

The regex performs the following operations:

```
(?<=[a-z])      # match is preceded by a lc letter
(?=[0-9#$*%])   # match is followed by a digit or punctuation char
|               # or
(?<=[0-9])      # match is preceded by a lc letter
(?=[a-z#$*%])   # match is followed by a lc letter or punctuation char
|               # or
(?<=[#$*%])     # match is preceded by a lc letter
(?=[a-z0-9])    # match followed by a lc letter or digit
```